# soundpool is not playing sound

Tags: android, soundpool

I am recording my user's voice and saving it to the sd card. but when i play it through soundpool it is not getting the right path of the file..
can any1 help me please regarding this..?
M saving this resorded audio file to sd card using AddRecordingToMediaLibrary() function.

Media Recording Code :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
          sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

          ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,singers);

               adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
               sp.setAdapter(adp);
          // store it to sd card
         //outFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
            //    getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecord.3gpp";

         File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
          try {
              outputFile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".m4a", sampleDir);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "No Memory Card Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
              return;
          }


          myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
          myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
          myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
          myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
          myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

          startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
          startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                start(v);
            }
          });

          stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
          stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stop(v);
            }
          });

          playBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
          playBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    play(v);    
            }
          });

          stopPlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopPlay);
          stopPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopPlay(v);
            }
          });

          playMod = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
          playMod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            playModified(v);    
            }


          });
       }

    public void playModified(View v)
       {

           spl = new SoundPool(1,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
           String path = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
           Toast.makeText(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           explosion = spl.load(path ,1);

          String sing = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
          if(explosion != 0 )
          {
              if(sing == "Singer1")
                    spl.play(explosion, 0.98F, 0.98F, 1, 0, 1.3F);                        
              else if(sing == "singer2")
                    spl.play(explosion, 0.3F, 0.3F, 0, 0, 2.0F);

              else if(sing == "singer3")
                    spl.play(explosion, 0.8F, 0.8F, 0, 0, 0.6F);
              else 
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "No File Found A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  return;
              }       
          }
          else 
          {
              Toast.makeText(this, "No File Found B",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              return;
          }

       }

 protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
       long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + outputFile);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
       ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

       Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
       newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

       sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
       Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Comment: You're missing the end quotation marks on the line if(sing == "Singer1)

Comment: @SoundConception yeah i got that... but its not the issue.. i place that there..

Comment: (1) We will try to fix most obvious problems first, so please fix your code in the question. (2) You say soundpool is not getting the right path. How do you know this? LogCat? Debug? The information you have given us so far does not indicate this in any way. I see you are new to S.O., so a quick tip... when asking a question it is usually best to assume we know nothing about your code and you have to tell us everything. :)

Comment: It's usually better to put more information than you think is necessary. Give us the related code around what you have already supplied. I see nothing intrinsically wrong with the code you have posted, apart from the syntax error.

Comment: @SoundConception Sorry for the inconvenience i have edited the code kindly do have a look at it again..
Thanx in advance.. :)

Comment: Thanks for update. So what happens when you run? Are you getting the "No File Found B" toast? If so, have you checked the SD card. Has a file actually been created?

Comment: No m not getting that toast actually it works fine even it goes into the if condition of "singer1" but its not playing the audio file.. 
when 
Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
this line of code executes it show me the path where file is being saved.. but that path is in media library i think not in sdcard.

Comment: Have you set the permission in your manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: yes i have set the permission.

Comment: and 1 more thing the sound file is created in sdcard..